# How to send the SMS using number in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms

I have stored the contact numbers in an array and then passed this array to message controller like the below code and printed the value of `controller.recipients` and its showing null.

```
  MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
  NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:selContacts];
  controller.recipients = arr;
 NSLog(@"received:- %@",controller.recipients);
 controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
 controller.body =@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/Click Here to Download!";
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: print [NSArray arrayWithArray:selContacts] is there any contact?

Comment: in which device you are debugging?

Comment: Yes, 5 to 6 contacts are there

Comment: This is the array printed in log (
    4155553695,
    4085553514,
    8885551212,
    5555228243,
    7075551854,
    5556106679
)

Comment: After printing NSLog(@"received:- %@",controller.recipients);         received:- (null)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [warningAlert show];
    return;

}
NSArray *recipents = @[@"+919999999999"];
NSString *message = @"Enter message here!";
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[messageController setRecipients:recipents];
[messageController setBody:message];
// Present message view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```